# Can imports point to a variable

Tags: sass

Is there a way to point the imports parameter to a variable?

```
@import $variable_name
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) says:

> Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain
>   restrictions. It’s **not possible to dynamically import a Sass file
>   based on a variable**; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such,
>   it only works with url() imports. For example:

```
$family: unquote("Droid+Sans");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{$family}");
```

> would compile to

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans");
```

So probably, the answer to your question will be that what you are trying to do, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - too bad about the lack of support for scss :(